# memory leaks tool for c# .net

Tags: .net, memory, valgrind, memory-leaks

What is the best way to detect memory leaks in c# .net ?

We are trying to find the cause of memory leaks on an application thats already installed and runing on a server

So visual studio profiler is not an option.

I worked with valgrind on linux,
its a tool that actualy showed me, for example, the file names
and line numbers in the code where i initialized the variables that are never disposed of..

however, valgrind only works on linux,

Are there good tools like that for .net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Ants Profiler Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) by Red Gate software

> ANTS Performance Profiler is an application profiler for .NET desktop,
>   ASP.NET, and ASP.NET MVC applications:
>
> - Find performance bottlenecks fast by profiling both the .NET code and    the data access layer
> - Get rich performance data, right-down to line-level timings and    expensive database queries
> - Save time going round in circles diagnosing and debugging – let the    profiler do the hard work for you
> - Explore unfamiliar code bases

Also check [How to identify memory leaks in the common language runtime](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318263)

Comment: visual studio has a built in memory profiler :)

Comment: Your content is completely irrelevant except the link provided.